# Saving a webpage to text file

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to save a webpage as text file, using the following function:

```
def html_to_txt(): 
    import urllib.request 
    url = str(input('Enter URL: ')) 
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url) 
    with open(str(input('Enter filename: ')), "w") as f: 
        for x in page: 
            f.write(str(x).replace('\\n','\n')) 
    s= 'Done' 
    return s
```

It gives a correct output, that means I can save a given webpage. But, the final text file contains a `b'` before the very first line, and a `'b'` before each following line.

Here's a sample output of my function (taken from: `http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P57052.txt`)

```
$ cat P57052.txt
b'ID   RBM11_HUMAN             Reviewed;         281 AA.
'b'AC   P57052; Q6YNC2; Q8NBA1; Q8NFF6;
'b'DT   01-DEC-2000, integrated into UniProtKB/Swiss-Prot.
'b'DT   01-DEC-2000, sequence version 1.
'b'DT   09-JUL-2014, entry version 111.
'b'DE   RecName: Full=Splicing regulator RBM11;
'b'DE   AltName: Full=RNA-binding motif protein 11;
'b'GN   Name=RBM11;
```

I wonder if it has something to do with binary file "default", I mean, if the webpage is  automatically saved with binary features by my python script.

Thanks in advance for your review.

Comment: I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving the cleanliness of existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a review, the code needs some work with regard separation of concerns. A single function shouldn't get user input, get a URL and write to a file. If you try to write unit tests for it, you'll quickly see it's better to split the functionality.

With regard to the problem, try something as follows:

```
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P57052.txt'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(response.read())
```

I hope this helps.